# Having trouble loading images with Pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, loading

I am having trouble importing an image. This is the code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))

pygame.display.set_caption("programing with pygame")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
         pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), 
pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
         pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), 
pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
        pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), 
pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
        pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), 
pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 50
y = 400
width = 64
height = 64
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))

if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
    walkCount = 0
if left:
    window.blit(walkLeft[walkCount]//3, (x,y))
    walkCount += 1
elif right:
    window.blit(walkRight[walkCount]//3, (x,y))
    walkCount += 1
else:
    window.blit(char, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()

#mainloop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkCount = 0
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    redrawGameWindow()



pygame.quit()
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\pygametest.py", line 8, in <module>
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('R2.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
        pygame.error: Couldn't open R1.png
```

Comment: That usually happens if a file doesn't exist or the file or pathnames are incorrect. Check out if the file is actually present (in this case it should be in the same directory as your `pygametest.py` file) and if it's named correctly.

Comment: how do i put in in the same directory

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to put your game files into the Python directory. Just create a new directory elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the image files are in the same folder as your pygametest.py? If not either move those files into the Python37-32 folder or change the pygame.image.load() location.

for example... pygame.image.load('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\R3.png')

hope this helps